# Split string with space but only get first word

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm having problem to split the string with space as a delim. I have tried 2 of the proposed solution as in here:
[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)
(using copy + istringstream and split method)

However, no matter what I did, the vector only get the first word (not the rest). When I use the split method, it's working with anything else (dot, comma, semi colon...) but not space.

Here is my current code, can you tell me what I get wrong? Or how I should try to approach the fix?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> textVector;
    std::string textString;

    std::cout << "Input command : ";
    std::cin >> textString;

    std::istringstream iss(textString);
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(textVector));

    for (int i = 0 ; i < textVector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << textVector[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The runnable code: http://cpp.sh/8nzq

Comment: Seems to [work fine for me](http://cpp.sh/4svr)

Comment: I think it's correct too but somehow it just doesn't work with space. Can you think of any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the example I linked *does* split on spaces. Can you show an example where it does not?

Comment: How do you initialize the `textString` variable? I suspect the problem can be there...

Comment: http://cpp.sh/8nzq. This is the code. Maybe it's the problem with the iterator?

Comment: The culprit is `std::cin >> textString;`, it only puts there the first word

Comment: so I think I should use getline instead? I haven't paid much attention into the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is simple, `std::cin >> textString` only reads until first whitespace. So `textString` only contains the first word.

To read entire line, you should instead use: [`std::getline(std::cin, textString);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Thanks. I thought the problem is with the split :D

Comment: It's common problem to "think", to assume, instead of to "verify". I would go as far as to say, when ever things stop making sense, it's time to stop thinking for a while, and just do some testing, usually either with a debugger, or with debug prints, or with a separate dummy test program :-)

Comment: ... and that's why we _require_ a [complete, minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Because you should already have done your due diligence with one.